# Trying to insert rows into table using sqlplus in a shell script hangs until grant

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-grant

I have a bash shell script in a AIX box from where I am trying to execute a ORACLE sql query kept in another file . If the query in the file is a SELECT, I am able to see the results.

However if the query is an insert , the script just hangs . I logged into toad as SYSDBA and executed the below command :

GRANT INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON DEVADMIN.TABLE_NAME TO PUBLIC;

On execution of this grant query , the script stops hanging ,executes fine and inserts the rows.

However the next time I run the script , the shell script again hangs . When I login to toad and execute the above grant query , the shell script is able to insert.

Why do I need to grant the same privileges multiple times or am I doing something wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you do the insert from sqlplus console? And you do a commit, do you?

Comment: Guys , i think i was able to figure out . Let me know if this sounds right . I was inserting the rows from shell script & doing a commit .  To run the script again , I used to delete the rows using TOAD tool - but NOT do a commit !  So when I run the script again , it used to hang . The tables have unique constraints.

Comment: ...

So when i delete the rows using TOAD and do a commit  , I am able to insert rows using the script .

Comment: @user1117723 every open commit hangs any other operation on the table(s) altered, even select. Don't know for sure about truncate or drop. Very common pitfall.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, writers don't block readers in Oracle. You can query the table even while other sessions have uncommitted changes.

Comment: (A note: this question has nothing to do with shell-scripts; please try to avoid mis-leading topic-titles)
Most likely you keep forgetting COMMIT in Toad, but command GRANT involves implicit COMMIT.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I have different examples in my mind, but perhaps I'm confusing it with DB2. I faintly remember that there are also options on the database that affect this behavior.  Sometimes it is more important that a query doesn't hang, and sometimes it is more important that it includes the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hanging often means waiting for locks.  These may be unique constraints.  They may be row locks.  They may be something else.

In these cases, the obvious question is what is waiting on what.

In Oracle the place to start looking is usually the `dba_lock` view which lists all latches and locks requested.

The funny behavior you are seeing in oracle is probably due to the fact that certain utility and ddl statements implicitly commit open transactions, thus releasing the locks.